# Batch script to change a value in a registry key for templates of Microsoft Office products

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry

I want to change the default template of some Microsoft Office products on a bunch of computers. Everything is working perfectly, except for the template to be pinned at the start screen of the MS Office products.

I found the registry key to get them pinned there which saves the path of the template which I want to change with a batch file quickly.

The information about the pinned template is saved with the two registry values `Item 1` and `Item Metadata 1` and the path is

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Recent Templates\ADAL_5DBCF6AC9A27C96B299D94D181DD223A6B8AB341FAFC42E9CFCFA1E61E3B69A6\File MRU
```

The data of `Item 1` is:

```
[F00000001][T01D83DF9542BD760][O00000000]*C:\Users\test\Documents\Benutzerdefinierte Office-Vorlagen\template.xltx
```

The data of `Item Metadata 1` is:

```
<Metadata><AppSpecific><id>C:\Users\test\Documents\Benutzerdefinierte Office-Vorlagen\template.xltx</id><nm>template</nm><du>C:\Users\test\Documents\Benutzerdefinierte Office-Vorlagen\template.xltx</du></AppSpecific></Metadata>
```

The new data has a different template name and needs the `%username%` environment variable reference to be used to match to the logged in user.

The problem here is that the path of the key starting with `ADAL_` has a random value.

I already looked up some threads where was searched for some registry keys and to delete them. So far I am able to find the keys with

```
reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Recent Templates" /s /f "Item"
```

I tried to get the output of the query command assigned to an environment variable to use it in a `reg add` command, but can't find a working method with a `for /f` loop, the always changing key path and the user name in the data.

Can somebody help me out on how to get a short batch script to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following batch file should do the task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Recent Templates" /s /f "Item 1" 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I" == "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Recent" set "RegKey=%%I %%J" & goto UpdateRegistry
for /F "tokens=1*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Recent Templates" /s /f "File MRU" 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I" == "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Recent" set "RegKey=%%I %%J" & goto UpdateRegistry
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Recent Templates" 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Recent Templates\ADAL_"') do set "RegKey=%%I\File MRU" & goto UpdateRegistry
echo ERROR: No "Item 1", "File MRU" or ADAL_ subkey found in Windows registry!
exit /B
:UpdateRegistry
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD "%RegKey%" /f /v "Item 1" /t REG_SZ /d "[F00000001][T01D83DF9542BD760][O00000000]*%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Benutzerdefinierte Office-Vorlagen\template.xltx" >nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD "%RegKey%" /f /v "Item Metadata 1" /t REG_SZ /d "<Metadata><AppSpecific><id>%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Benutzerdefinierte Office-Vorlagen\template.xltx</id><nm>template</nm><du>%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Benutzerdefinierte Office-Vorlagen\template.xltx</du></AppSpecific></Metadata>" >nul
endlocal
```

It is necessary to split up the first non-empty line into two substrings on first space character with assigning the first substring (token) to loop variable `I` and the rest of the line to next loop variable `J` to be able to verify with the **IF** condition doing a case-insensitive string comparison that the searched registry value `Item 1` respectively registry key `File MRU` is found at all by the first two registry queries.

The third registry query processes just the subkeys of the specified key without searching for a registry value or a subkey at all and therefore processes always the entire output lines not being empty. Here is used **FIND** to make sure having found the right registry key starting with `ADAL_` in the specified registry key.

It is possible that the registry key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Recent Templates
```

does not exist at all because of the user has not started Excel and clicked on tab **File** (German: **Datei**) up to now. This use case results in the error message on execution of the batch script above.

Run in a command prompt window the following two commands for the reason of using `%USERPROFILE%`:

```
reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
```

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `reg` command line (with `find`) with using a separate command process started in background.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `find /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg add /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the operators `&` and `&&`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working like a charm. The redirection operators was the missing part I was not aware of.